# Chrome and chromeDriver mismatch

Tags: python, java, selenium, testing, automation

So at my current job I’m at a pinch, we can’t just download executable jars and use them. We have to request to download whatever we want . So the problem is , our chrome gets auto updated where as we need to ask for permission to download chromeDriver(all drivers in general). This is a lengthy process and is not feasible . By the time they approve it, a new version of chrome is usually out . So It’s very difficult to get the automation testing started , our chrome and chrome driver versions are always different . I was planning to use Java with selenium but at this point , this is blocking it from happening .

Is there any alternative to this ? I tried using webdriverManager but that dependency is not in our dependency library so that’s not a option aswell. Our system blocks the required files to download when trying to implement that dependency.

At this point , I’m even willing to use python if there is a way to ignore the webdriver executable jar issue . Is there any kind of framework I can use that dosent require a instance of webdriver .

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other E2E testing frameworks. We went from Selenium to https://www.cypress.io/ and it was a huge improvement.

Comment: Dosent cypress require chrome driver ?

Comment: No, and it supports multiple browsers.

Comment: THE ISSUE IS I CANT get any drivers

Comment: Frustrating, sound like your biggest problemen isn't which framework to use or even a technical one, it's an organizational problem. I'm sorry.